# issue with pivot table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

i have a problem with my pivot table in laravel i have a `Product`, `Category` tables with a `category_product` pivit table defined like this

```
Schema::create('category_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();

    });
```

then in my product class

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

and in the category class

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

when i try to do this

```
$product->categories()->attach(Category::find([3,4]));
```

the behavior is somewhat funny
first only one category gets attached and when i try again i get a mysql error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '3' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `category_product` (`category_id`, `id`, `product_id`) values (0, 3, 2), (1, 4, 2))
```

which is very strange.
then i took a look at the database and i got this
[image]

Comment: I thought you only need to pass in the ids, not the entire model.

Comment: i get the same result when i pass the ids

Comment: from the image i put up, the category_id value is inserted in the id column. i don't know why

Comment: Can you try the sync method instead? And use the ids

Comment: I tried... Same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use 'newPivotQuery' like this:

```
$product->categories()->newPivotQuery()->insert([
['category_id'=>3,'product_id'=>$product->id],
['category_id'=>4,'product_id'=>$product->id]
]);
```

newPivotQuery() allows you to make queries directly on pivot table